# Maintaining .dsw and .dsp files in Source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

Is it advisable to maintain .dsw or .dsp files under source control with periodic check ins and check outs depending on the projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course! Otherwise how would other developers know to add new files to the project when you add one to your project? You'd have to tell them, which would defeat the purpose of source control!*

You would check in changes to your solution/project files every time they're modified, just like any other file.

* Well, not entirely

Comment: But somehow in our team we tend not to maintain dsw and dsp in source control apparently due to some fear which we have not yet figured out. So we will be changing that shortly and make it a habit to update the same.

Comment: Upvote for Dean.  @ckv Did you figure out the "fear"?  That's a weird one, I gotta admit.

Comment: My guess is that it's because it's a `Microsoft Developer Studio Generated Build File`?  And you generally want to avoid adding generated files to SC.